# UI automation for Unity app

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, mobile, automation

I am trying to write test for UI automation for mobile app, developed in Unity. But UI tool, like Appium, Expresso etc support only native UI and does not support GUI for Unity app. so, i am having problem to detect the locators to perform actions (click, press or assert).

Do you know how to automate UI of Unity app? I have used XY position of images by pixel, but it is not useful due device diversity.

Thanks.

Comment: the following free script in the asset store might help you out  
[Unity UI Test Automation](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/72693)

Comment: It run test on Editor or  Unity Player. I need to test app from real device (android or IOS). Thanks

Comment: Did you try using it? It says in the description it has been tested on Android, iOS and Standalone.

Comment: I have installed and run on editor. But not able to build. it is giving me error: Assets/UITest/Examples/UITestExample.cs(19,0): error CS1517: Invalid preprocessor directive. I did not touch the code. Just installed and built.

Answer (score 2):

My company (http://altom.ro) has just released an open source Unity plugin that helps with mobile UI Automation for Unity using Appium.

We support Python so far, and we use a socket connection to get information about Unity elements from the Python Appium scripts:
[image]

Useful links:

- Source code: https://gitlab.com/altom/altunitytester
- Unity Asset Store link: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/altunitytester-112101
- Getting Started Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uTO-Uzt3AEQ&t=0s
- Blog post with more info on it: http://altom.ro/blog/altunitytester-unity-using-appium

We are looking into developing the same from within Unity Editor, in C#, and integrating it with Unity Test Runner, but that's just work in progress at the moment.